# Conversão de integer no Controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, int, conversão

Tenho os seguintes dados no controller:

```
$sheets = printerChange::select('folhas');
$sheetsNew = printerChange::select('folhasnew');
$sheetsCompare = (int)$sheetsNew;

if(!is_null($sheetsCompare > 0)){
   $calcSheets->folhasnew = $request->folhas - $calcSheets->folhas;
}
else{
   $calcSheets->folhasnew = $request->folhas;
}
```

Quando executo, o seguinte erro aparece no meu browser:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to int

Eu pesquisei bastante na internet e não consegui achar nada que me ajudasse, vi várias formas de conversão mas nenhuma me ajudou até este ponto.

Será algo de errado em minha sintaxe?

PS: como banco de dados estou usando o PostgreSQL.

Comment: Isso é no controller? poderia postar seu model também?qual versão do laravel está utilizando?

Comment: Bom dia Alvaro,

meu Model está assim:

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class printerChange extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'transicao';

    protected $primaryKey = 'idtransicao';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public $increment = false;
}


A versão do laravel que eu estou usando é a 5.7...
Comecei a aprender PHP e laravel muito recentemente.

De qualquer forma, muito obrigado.

Comment: outra coisa dê um `var_dump` na variável `$sheetsNew` antes de tentar fazer a conversão

Comment: Você está tentando converter uma collection em int, isso nunca vai funcionar, você deve dar um count() na variável $sheetsNew;
$sheetsCompare = count($sheetsNew);

Comment: Kayo, se eu fizer $sheetsNew = printerChange::select('folhasnew')->first(); no lugar de $sheetsNew = printerChange::select('folhasnew');
Poderia dar certo?

Comment: Já tentou assim: $sheetsCompare = (int) ($sheetsNew->get());

Comment: Oi fajuchem, eu tentei da forma que você sugeriu mas o erro continua o mesmo...
Na verdade eu me deparei com uma coisa, no meu campo folhasnew da tabela o valor não é 0, não tem nada no valor, será que eu deveria popular esse campo com 0 desde o início?

Comment: Tente fazer assim: `sheetsNew =  printerChange::select('folhasnew')->count()`

Comment: Pessoal, muito obrigado pela ajuda, não sei se é certo mas eu coloquei o código dentro de um foreach e funcionou, quer dizer, funcionou em termos, o erro não aparece mais mas, meu campo folhasnew continua com valor null...
De qualquer forma, acho que essa já é uma outra questão né...

Comment: Ou tenta assim: `DB::table('folhasnew')->count();`

Comment: Obrigado adventistaam, mas se eu fizer um count();, não vai me retornar a contagem de valores do campo folhasnew? a contagem de vezes que esse campo aparece com dados?

Comment: Pessoal, desculpem a demora em voltar aqui mas consegui resolver me problema alterando o meu select, ficou assim:$oldsheet = printerChange::latest('folhas')
                ->where('marca', $request->marca)
                ->where('modelo', $request->modelo)
                ->where('toner', $request->toner)
                ->where('marca_toner', $request->tonerMarca)
                ->first();

Comment: A outra variável:
$pageCount = printerChange::latest('folhasnew')
                ->where('marca', $request->marca)
                ->where('modelo', $request->modelo)
                ->where('toner', $request->toner)
                ->where('marca_toner', $request->tonerMarca)
                ->first();

Comment: O calculo em si:
if(is_null($pageCount)){
                $printerChange->folhasnew = 0;
            }
            elseif($pageCount->folhasnew >= 0){
                $printerChange->folhasnew = 0;
                $pageCount->folhasnew = $request->folhas - $oldsheet->folhas;
            }